# gen_snapshot.exe error occurred while build release apk or singh apk

Tags: windows, flutter, dart

[image]

This error occurred while I was trying to create a release apk. Even with Singh apk.
I try to find a solution but can't find a suitable solution. Thank you for your help

Comment: Did you manage to fix the problem?